# KineticJS place object inside another complex object (e.g. Kinetic.Path)

Tags: javascript, kineticjs

I have a world map created by KineticJS. Every country is a complex Kinetic.Path.

Is there a way to programmatically place another object (e.g. a circle) inside a country? I know from drag and drop that you have to do your own math to calculate the container object's position(width,height and offsets etc), and it's complicated enough with a simple rectangle.

But this way seems impossible to me with a complex Kinetic.Path with many many sides.

Comment: Why don't you create a group with path and circle, and position the circle within this group  (automatically respective to your path)?

Comment: I haven't tryed grouping yet. What do you mean by position the circle within this group?

Comment: Let me check if I understood correctly your question. You need to put the circle in the country, no? But you find the math to do that too cumbersome. What I am telling is, if your path and circle were in a group, the position (x,y) of the circle would be always relative to the path, i.e. if you need to re-position your path, just move the group, the circle will move respectively without losing its position on the path.

Comment: I tried it and the problem is that I can't get the position of the group/path/objectingroup. Everything always returns {0,0}. I guess the problem is, that the country paths are positioned by coordinates, not by x and y values.